# Matrix Representation of a Discretization for a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: pde, finite-difference, discretization

I want to discretize the following problem

\begin{cases}
      \mu \nabla^2u+(\lambda+\mu)\nabla \nabla\cdot u = \rho \frac{\partial^2u  }{\partial t^2 } +  \beta \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\
 u(x,y,t) = c, (x,y) \in \partial( [0,L_{x}]\times [0,L_{y}]), t \in [0,T]\\
u(x,y,0) = u_{0}(x,y), (x,y) \in [0,L_{x}]\times [0,L_{y}]\\
\frac{\partial u(x,y,0)}{\partial t} = u_{1}(x,y), (x,y) \in [0,L_{x}]\times [0,L_{y}]\\
\end{cases}

where $T,L_{x},L_{y} >0$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$
and  $$ u_{0},u_{1} \in C^2( [0,L_{x}]\times [0,L_{y}], \mathbb{R^2} ) $$
$$u \in C^2( [0,L_{x}]\times [0,L_{y}]\times [0,T], \mathbb{R^2} ) $$

My attempt. 
Let $u = ( u_{x} \ u_{y} )^T$

$$ \mu \nabla^2u = ( \mu \nabla^2 u_{x} \ \  \mu \nabla^2u_{y} )^T =  $$ 
$$\mu \begin{pmatrix}
\nabla^2 & 0 \\
0 & \nabla^2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} u_{x}\\ u_{y} \end{pmatrix} $$

where the laplacian in the Kronecker product is: $$ \nabla^2 = L_{2}\otimes I_{n_{x}} + I_{n_{y}} \otimes L_{2} $$

\begin{equation} 
   L_{2} = \frac{1}{h^2}\left[\begin{matrix}
-2 & 1 & & 0\\
1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & 1 & -2 \end{matrix} \right]
\end{equation}

$h$ is the step size or mesh size... Now

$$ (\lambda+\mu)\nabla \nabla \cdot u =  $$
$$ \begin{pmatrix} (\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial^2 u_{x}}{\partial x^2} + (\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial^2 u_{y}}{\partial x \partial y}\\
(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial^2 u_{x}}{\partial y \partial x}+(\lambda+\mu)\frac{\partial^2 u_{y}}{\partial y^2} 
\end{pmatrix} = $$

$$ (\lambda+\mu) \begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}  & \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \\ 
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y \partial x} &  \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2} 
   \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_{x} \\ u_{y}  \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2} = L_{2}\otimes I_{n_{x}} $$
$$ \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2} =  I_{n_{y}} \otimes L_{2}$$

My question is how do I represent the following operators in terms of $L_{2}, I, \otimes$ or is not possible ? if it is not possible, what is the matrix representation of...?

$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} = \textbf{ ? }$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y \partial x} = \textbf{ ? }$$

Thank you!

EDIT: PHYSICAL INTERPRETATION
This is known as the wave equation in elastodynamic (a more general form)

where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the Lame’s coefficients given by

$$ \mu = \frac{E}{2(1+\upsilon)}  $$ and 
$$ \lambda = \frac{E\upsilon}{(1+\upsilon)(1-2\upsilon)} $$

where $E$ is the modulus of elasticity (Young modulus) and $\upsilon$ is the
Poisson’s ratio of the elastic material. $\rho$ is the linear density.

Comment: Which physical problem does this equation represent ?

Comment: The term $\upsilon\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ is unusual; this could represent some kind of viscous damping. In any event, the coefficient would not be Poisson's ratio. You probably want to recheck this.

Comment: ok, I have changed the coefficient's name,  maybe to simplify the problem we can consider $\beta = 0 $...what I need is the matrix representation of the mixed derivatives, because I have not worked with that operator. I'm stuck in that part of the discretization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1D,  if we define $u_{k} := u(x_{k}) $;    $\ \  x_{k} = kh $  and $ \ \ k = 0,1,2,...,N$. $h$ is known as the mesh size or step size.
I want to approximate the first derivative using central difference:

$$ \frac{du_{k}}{dx} \approx \frac{ u_{k+1}-u_{k-1}  }{ 2h } = \frac{ -u_{k-1} +u_{k+1}  }{ 2h }   $$

In this problem (1D) if  $u(0) = u_{0} = 0$ and $ u(L) = u(x_{N}) = u_{N} = 0 $ we get the following matrix representation of the first derivative

\begin{equation} 
   \frac{d}{dx} \approx L_{1} = \frac{1}{2h}\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & & 0\\
-1 & \ddots & \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & 1 \\
0 & & -1 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
\end{equation}

Now using $L_{1}$:

$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} = \Big((L_{1})_{n_{x}} \otimes I_{n_{y}} \Big)\Big( I_{n_{x}} \otimes (L_{1})_{n_{y}}   \Big) = { (L_{1})_{n_{x}} \otimes (L_{1})_{n_{y}}  }  $$

I have used the mixed-product property for kronecker product. 
$$ (\mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B})(\mathbf{C} \otimes \mathbf{D}) = (\mathbf{AC}) \otimes (\mathbf{BD})$$.

In a similar way we get:

$$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y \partial x} =  (L_{1})_{ n_{y} }   \otimes  (L_{1})_{n_{x}}  $$